# Installing HBase Explorer

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, hbase

Hi folks I want to install Hbase explorer on my ubuntu but didn't get any good help from anywhere. Please guide me about that.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking for a tool to manage Hbase tables, then i would suggest the following tool.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/hbasemanagergui/?source=directory

Its simple, and more importantly, it helps to insert and delete data, applying filters on column qualifiers. Have a try.

Comment: it seems very helpful snd good but but it is a simple jar file - how can i use it?

Comment: Download it, you should be having a java run time environment in your system.Double click and there you are, ready to go.                      Feel free to contact in case of doubts. :)

Comment: Thank jayan it is wonderful :) - I just need to know about the connection parameters as i given my HBase servers IP in "hbase.master" field and remote system IP from where i am connecting with hbase in "hbase.zookeeper.quorum" field but i am confused about client port - Is the previous parameters that i given are right?

Comment: hbase.master should be The host and port that the HBase master runs at.        
For Eg: 127.0.0.1:6000 or localhost:6000

hbase.zookeeper.quorum should be Comma separated list of servers in the ZooKeeper Quorum.I have only one value given, which is 127.0.0.1

hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort is the port at which the clients will connect. In my case, the value is 2181(the default one)

Comment: Thnx jayan :) It is wonderful

Answer (score 0):

Hbase Explorer is a Webapp deployed on tomcat. The easiest way to run it is to download the standalone version from [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hbaseexplorer/)
and install it according to the RUNNING.txt file in the zip archive. You then start the tomcat webapp using a startup.sh script and surf over to http://localhost:8080. You should see a Hbase Explorer login page in your browser. You need to have HBase running as well. Get this far, if you have any more questions post them with an example of what you have tried.

Comment: Is there a step by step on installing HBase explorer? thanks.